# I want to handle the link clicked in a QWebView

Tags: qt, qwebview

so this is my problem : I would like to handle a clicked link in a `QWebView`. There is the signal

`void QWebView::linkClicked ( const QUrl & url )`

that is emitted when the user clicks on a link, so I could use that for my purposes, but it depends of the value of  `linkDelegationPolicy property` that is set by default to not delegate links

but I can't change this because it's a function of `QWebPage` and I have a `QWebView` and `QWebView` doesn't inherit from `QWebPage`...so I'm really confused

Any help please! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QWebView has an underlying QWepPage. You can get a pointer to it using the method [QWebView::page()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebview.html#page).

Comment: Amazing thanks!!! I'm feel kind of stupid for something that simple lol thanks again!